# How to include additional words for spell check in html?

Tags: javascript, html, spell-checking

I am able to do spell check in html using the code below but I want to include medical words as well, as a custom dictionary to this spell check. Is there a method to do this ?

```
# Syntax for spellcheck attribute in an input field in html:
<input type="text" spellcheck="value">
```

Comment: The `spellcheck` attribute is used to let the browser know that you want it to check spelling in that element. You cannot add/remove words from the browser's dictionary. You might want to look into Javascript solutions, rather then using this attribute.

Comment: are you aware of any javascript based solution. can you point it to me